# Мог ли телефон заразиться вирусом?

Tags: android, безопасность

К примеру, я скачал .apk файл (но не устанавливал приложение, просто apk файл), проверил на вирустотале, больше половины антивирусов показали, что файл заражен. После этого я удалил apk-файл. Есть ли шанс того, что я поймал вирус, если я не устанавливал apk?

Comment: Нет, не мог. С чего?

Comment: Ну если только на вирусном сайте были. Но тогда не важно, качали вы файл или нет.

Comment: Качал на 4PDA, форум такой. У меня вопрос общего характера, скачал вирусный apk, но не открывал его, есть шанс заразиться вирусом?

Comment: Любой вирус, который не был выполнен, является просто набором байт. Ведь вирус - та же программа, просто с вредными намерениями.

Comment: 4PDA — не вирусный сайт. От скачивания заразиться телефон не мог. А есть симптомы заражения?

Comment: Симптомов нет, вроде не болею. Ну а если серьезно, я параноик

Comment: параноики обычно с кнопочным телефоном ходят и аккумулятор вставляют только когда нужно позвонить

Comment: Я еще тором пользуюсь не для выхода в белый интернет, я тогда не параноик, а кто?